# Pandas rolling function on categorical variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
group cat
1     0
2     0
1     0
1     1
2     0
2     1 
1     2
1     2
```

I'm trying to group the data by `group`, then applies a custom function to the past 5 rows.
The custom function looks like this

```
def unalikeability(data):

    num_observations = data.shape[0]
    counts = data.value_counts()

    return 1 - ((counts / num_observations)**2).sum()
```

Desired output:

```
group unalikeability
1     result calculated by the function
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

I can get the past 5 rows using `groupby().rolling()`, but the `rolling` object in pandas doesn't have the `shape`/ `value_counts` attribute and method like a DataFrame. I tried creating a `DataFrame` from the rolling object, but this isn't allowed either.

Comment: provide your desired output of input

Comment: @PandaKim editted it in

Comment: While you may value your own time, the time of others who answer your questions is likely even more valuable. desired output is requested for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) your function. Depending on whether you want the output to be computed only on full chunks (5 values), or chunks of any size, use `min_periods`:

```
def unalikeability(data):

    num_observations = data.shape[0]
    counts = data.value_counts()

    return 1 - ((counts / num_observations)**2).sum()

# compute the score only if we have 5 rows
df['out1'] = (df.groupby('group')
                .rolling(5)['cat']
                .apply(unalikeability)
                .droplevel('group')
              )

# compute the score with incomplete chunks
df['out2'] = (df.groupby('group')
                .rolling(5, min_periods=1)['cat']
                .apply(unalikeability)
                .droplevel('group')
              )
```

Output:

```
   group  cat  out1      out2
0      1    0   NaN  0.000000
1      2    0   NaN  0.000000
2      1    0   NaN  0.000000
3      1    1   NaN  0.444444
4      2    0   NaN  0.000000
5      2    1   NaN  0.444444
6      1    2   NaN  0.625000
7      1    2  0.64  0.640000
```

Comment: Is `apply` the only way to turn a `Rolling` object into a `DataFrame`?

Comment: You can see the rolling object as a collection of sub-DataFrames, to come back to individual rows you have to aggregate. This can be done by a method like `mean`/`sum`/... but in the car if an arbitrary function you indeed have to use `apply`

Comment: \*case of (autocorrect)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def unalikeability(data):
    num_observations = data.shape[0]
    counts = data.value_counts()
    return 1 - ((counts / num_observations) ** 2).sum()


df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'cat': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2]})
print(df)
window_size = 5
def g(df):
    # Reverse and reset index
    shifted_data = df.cat.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
    df['unalikeability']  = [unalikeability(shifted_data.iloc[max(0, i- window_size +1) : i +1])
                            for i in range(len(df))]
    return df 
    
    
    
out = df.groupby('group').apply(g).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)    
"""
  group  cat  unalikeability
0      1    0        0.000000
1      1    0        0.000000
2      1    1        0.444444
3      1    2        0.625000
4      1    2        0.640000
5      2    0        0.000000
6      2    0        0.500000
7      2    1        0.444444
"""
```